# Add HTML Link to Google Maps Circle Element

Tags: javascript, google-maps, hyperlink, onclicklistener, geometry

I am sure there is a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to find it within the Google Maps online documentation. I have a map with several circles and the idea is that clicking on the circle will open up a new HTML page.

For each circle.....

Lat Long is defined:

```
var NZNorth=new google.maps.LatLng( -38.929764,176.009002);
```

Circle Variables:

```
var Circle1 = new google.maps.Circle({
center:NZNorth,
 radius:250000,
 strokeColor:"#FA0014",
 strokeOpacity:1,
 strokeWeight:1,
 fillColor:"#FA0014",
 fillOpacity:0.2
 });
```

Call the Circle:

```
Circle1.setMap(map);
```

So to add a hyperlink onclick of the circle what do I need to do? I am not sure if I have to declare the link for each circle and then include an onclick function in each circle variable?

As always thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Incase anyone has the same problem, add the URL to your variable

```
var Circle1 = new google.maps.Circle({
center:NZNorth,
radius:250000,
strokeColor:"#FA0014",
strokeOpacity:1,
strokeWeight:1,
fillColor:"#FA0014",
fillOpacity:0.2,
URL:'http://www.bbc.co.uk'
});
```

Then add the listener!

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Circle1, 'click', function() {

 window.location = Circle1.URL; 

});
```

Comment: Please mark this as solution, so the question doesn't stay open and unsolved.

Answer (score 2):

Circle throws an "click" event. So you must [add a listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) to it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, below is the solution